# Toggle button border space

Tags: html, css, sass, overflow, toggle

There is some space between border and background as presented on the screenshot. It's connected to the border-radius and overflow: hidden.
If I remove border radius everywhere it works fine. I would like to remove that spacing. I tested it on Chrome and Firefox.

Screen Toggler border artefacts

[image]

Screen Toggler border artefacts highlighted

[image]

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track {
  border-color: #4680fe;
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track .toggle__circle {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track .toggle__handler {
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out 50ms, right 250ms ease-in-out, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  left: 24px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.input--hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: inherit;
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.input__row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toggle__track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: border 250ms 0ms linear;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.4);
}

.toggle__circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 250ms 0ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #4680fe;
}

.toggle__container,
.toggle__circle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
}

.toggle__handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 2px;
  right: 24px;
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out, right 250ms ease-in-out 50ms, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #4680fe;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle toggle--checked">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input--hidden" checked>
  <div class="input__row">
    <div class="toggle__container">
      <div class="toggle__track">
        <span class="toggle__circle"></span>
        <div class="toggle__handler"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: background-color: #4680FE; instead of transparent handles the artefacts but now the dot disappears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `background-color` for `.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track` should be able to fix the gap issue as not changing your effect as possible.

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track {
  border-color: #4680fe;
  background-color: #4680fe;
  transition: background-color 250ms ease;
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track .toggle__circle {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track .toggle__handler {
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out 50ms, right 250ms ease-in-out, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  left: 24px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.input--hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: inherit;
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.input__row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toggle__track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: border 250ms 0ms linear;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.4);
}

.toggle__circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 250ms 0ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #4680fe;
}

.toggle__container,
.toggle__circle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
}

.toggle__handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 2px;
  right: 24px;
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out, right 250ms ease-in-out 50ms, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #4680fe;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle toggle--checked">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input--hidden" checked>
  <div class="input__row">
    <div class="toggle__container">
      <div class="toggle__track">
        <span class="toggle__circle"></span>
        <div class="toggle__handler"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change background-color of .toggle__track #4680fe and .toggle__handler #ffffff

```css
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: visible;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track {
  border-color: #4680fe;
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track .toggle__circle {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}
.toggle input[type=checkbox]:checked + .input__row .toggle__container .toggle__track .toggle__handler {
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out 50ms, right 250ms ease-in-out, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  left: 24px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

.input--hidden {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: inherit;
  pointer-events: all;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.input__row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.toggle__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toggle__track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: border 250ms 0ms linear;
  background-color: #4680fe;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.1);
  border: 2px solid rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.4);
}

.toggle__circle {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: transform 250ms 0ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: #4680fe;
}

.toggle__container,
.toggle__circle {
  width: 48px;
  height: 24px;
}

.toggle__handler {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 16px;
  margin: 2px;
  right: 24px;
  transition: left 250ms ease-in-out, right 250ms ease-in-out 50ms, background-color 250ms ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(70, 128, 254, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="toggle toggle--checked">
  <input type="checkbox" class="input--hidden" checked>
  <div class="input__row">
    <div class="toggle__container">
      <div class="toggle__track">
        <span class="toggle__circle"></span>
        <div class="toggle__handler"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It causes the animation to behave differently. I would like to avoid using a solid background. Also I dont want to have #fff background - i need it to be transparent.